# Bulk export data out of Metatrader mt4 in csv format

Tags: metatrader4, forex, mt4

I wonder if this is possible to bulk export historical data for all available symbols out of Metatrader mt4 in csv format - please let me know if you have seen such a helpful but completely impossible to find script....

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an indicator so every symbols will bee available for you.

```
bool firststart=true;

int start()
{
  if(firststart)
  {
    export();
    firststart=false;
  }
}
```

so, your code will be run only once. and you can call each symbol by iHigh, Ilow etc...

if the question is how to check all symbols, the answer is here

https://docs.mql4.com/marketinformation/symbolstotal